# Consistent implementation functions in a logical order

Tags: php

Maybe I'm wrong to expressed it in the title, but I just do not understand how in the class like this.

```
<?php
    class sample{
        public $data = [];

        public function pushIndex($index){
            array_push($this->data, $index);
        }

        public function pushValue($value){
            array_push($this->data["index"], $value);

            // Some magic
        }

        public function forIndex($index){
            return $this->data[$index];

            // Some magic
        }
    }
```

To realize scheme like in Symfony, where will be spaghetti like this

```
<?php
    $a = new sample;
    $a->pushIndex("index")->pushValue("value");
    $a->forIndex("index2")->pushValue("value2");
```

Maybe someone knows how to do it?

Comment: So you try to implement something like this? If yes, why?!

Comment: @Rizier123, I want somehow to optimize the code for not check the data in each function. That check is done in one place, add an index for the second, and its value in the third.

Comment: This code smells!
Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're talking about is called [Fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).
Returns the current object by using $this.

```
public function pushIndex($index){
    array_push($this->a,$index);
    return $this;
}
```

But what you want is to do something like this:

```
class sample
{
    protected $a = [];
    protected $currentIndex = null;

    public function pushIndex($index)
    {
        $this->currentIndex = $index;
        return $this;
    }

    public function pushValue($value)
    {
        if ($this->currentIndex === null) {
            throw new LogicException('You need to call "pushIndex" or "forIndex" first.');
        }

        $this->a[$this->currentIndex] = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function forIndex($index)
    {
        if (!isset($this->a[$index])) {
            throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Index "%s" doesn\'t exists', $index));
        }

        $this->currentIndex = $index;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getArray()
    {
        return $this->a;
    }
}
```

```
$a = new sample;
$a->pushIndex("index")->pushValue("value");
$a->forIndex("index2")->pushValue("value2"); // exception?

var_dump($a->getArray());
```

But what you want is pretty unclear.

Comment: Thank you very much. I now understand at least logic.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to achieve is something like this:

```
class sample{
    public $a = [];
    public $index = null;
    public function pushIndex($index){
        $this->index = $index;
        $this->a[$index] = null;
        return $this;
    }
    public function pushValue($value){
        $this->a[$this->index] = $value;
        return $this;
    }
    public function forIndex($index){
        $this->index = $index;
        return $this;
    }
}


$a = new sample;
$a->pushIndex("index")->pushValue("value");
$a->forIndex("index2")->pushValue("value2");

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($a);
echo "</pre>";
```

This is called "method chaining". By returning a reference to the called object, you're able to perform further methods on the object, essentially "chaining" the methods.

I've had to adjust your code a little to get it the work I believe the way you want it to. It should provide a working example to help you understand method chaining.

Comment: Thank you very much. I now understand at least logic.

Comment: @MarkAnderson No problem. With the way this is written now you can even call all the methods as a single chain. It should work with whatever method you chain onto the next, so it's quite flexible. That's the power of method chaining.